# Input POST with same name input like PHP POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Extract of HTML form:

```
<input type="text" id="1" name="name[1]" class="input-number" onchange="input_onchange(this.id)" value="39" min="1" max="25">
<input type="text" id="1" name="name[2]" class="input-number" onchange="input_onchange(this.id)" value="39" min="1" max="25">
```

My AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/sepetim/ajax',
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
        //'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'name': $('input[name=name[' + id + ']]').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#fiyat').replaceWith("<span class='para fw6'>" + data.formattedPrice + " TL</span>");
    }
});
```

Extract from my controller:

```
public function  addStock(Request $request) {
    $data = new ShoppingCartDetail();
    $data->cart_id = $request->input("cart_id");
    $data->stock_id = $request->input("stock_id");
    $data->price = 1;
    $data->save();
    $data->name = $request->input("name");
    $data->price = 1200;
    $formattedPrice = number_format($data->name * $data->price, "2" , ",", ".");
    return response ()->json ([ "data" => $data , "formattedPrice" => $formattedPrice ]);
}
```

I think the offending line is this one:

```
$data->name = $request->input("name");
```

I have tried, but I cannot get the inputs with the name '*name*'?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't give more than one element the same ID; I've therefore renamed the second instance of id.

```
<input type="text" id="1" name="name[]" class="input-number" onchange="input_onchange(this.id)" value="39" min="1" max="25" />
<input type="text" id="2" name="name[]" class="input-number" onchange="input_onchange(this.id)" value="39" min="1" max="25" />
```

Also note that I have removed the indexes that you had given to the name attribute.
When specifying the name you only need the square brackets and it will be auto indexed.

The rest of the PHP code looks good.

The JavaScript code has some issues - whether this is in production or you copied and pasted a selection and forgot to format it accordingly.
The offending line is after `success`, there is a comma. I'm assuming this is that you just copied the top of that section, if this isn't the case then just remove the comma and that will fix that error.

Remember, when developing you can open the console (usually pressing F12) and you can view any errors that are related to the JavaScript code.